# Short polling using WebFlux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, polling, spring-webclient

I have this post method:

```
webClientBuilder
                .build()
                .get()
                .uri("uri")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, response -> Mono.error(new CustomException("Response is in status: ".concat(response.statusCode().toString()))))
                .bodyToMono(GetResponse.class)
                .log()
                .flatMap(response ->
                        Mono.fromSupplier(() -> updateMember(entity.getId(), getScore(response)))
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()))
                .block();
```

I should create a short poll on it, since the api I called could delay answering me, I should be able to call it several times, maybe every 3/5 seconds. The external service always gives me an answer, but I have to verify that a specific field in the answer is not null. I have to repeat it at most 5 times, if after 5 times it returns null, I will pass null to my method (updateMember).

I am trying something like this:

```
webClientBuilder
                .build()
                .get()
                .uri("uri")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, response -> Mono.error(new CustomException("response is in status: ".concat(response.statusCode().toString()))))
                .bodyToMono(GetResponse.class)
                .filter(response -> Objects.nonNull(response.getAnag().getSummary()))
                .repeatWhenEmpty(Repeat.onlyIf(repeatContext -> true)
                        .exponentialBackoff(Duration.ofSeconds(5), Duration.ofSeconds(10)).timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30)))
                .delaySubscription(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .flatMap(response -> Mono.fromSupplier(() -> updateMember(entity.getId(), response.getAnag().getSummary()))
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()))
                .block();
```

I would like to repeat at most 5 times, only if that value in the answer is null otherwise I pass the value directly.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you get a timeout exception because of the delay, you can add one of the '.retry()'s operators to the chain. Perhaps this will be helpful:

```
.retryWhen(Retry.fixedDelay(3, Duration.ofSeconds(3)))
```

[Example from reactor reference documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.exponentialBackoff)

Comment: it's more complicated, I should check that a field of their answer is non-null.

Comment: @EngineerTop if you have additional requirements then please include those in the question so that we can avoid people doing research and answering questions that don't fit the requirements.